# Cannot use source to execute Bash script on zsh

Tags: bash, shell, sed, zsh

I have a Mac, on which I have installed and configured zsh to be my default shell. It has worked very well with simple Bash scripts. Until today.

I was trying to set up my AWS CLI access with MFA and used a script to do the same. Since I have multiple accounts, I used an `aws_accounts` file to store the account numbers with `400` permissions on it. (No real reason why, just felt like it and it works).

I then `source` this file and get to the part where I need to provide my MFA key, and those work too. The last step, where I `export` the access key, secret key and session token, works as long as the script is executing, but once done, `echo`ing it shows a blank, because it now no longer has set it in the current shell.

I know the workaround is to do `source aws_mfa_access default` to run the script, but it doesn't work and I get a `bad substitution` error. I've tried various combinations of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`, but to no avail. What's going on?

[aws_account_numbers]

```
default_account_number=<number>
sandbox_account_number=<number>
production_account_number=<number>
```

[aws_mfa_access]

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source aws_account_numbers

AWS_ENV="${1}"
AWS_ACCT_NBR="${AWS_ENV}"_account_number

#export your aws access key that matches with your account, username
export AWS_PROFILE="${AWS_ENV}"

#If there are existing environment variables set, this can cause issues so we unset them first
unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

#Set the serial number of your MFA token
MFA="arn:aws:iam::${!AWS_ACCT_NBR}:mfa/codingincircles"

#Get the code from the MFA device
echo "Please enter the MFA code for the ${AWS_ENV} account: "
read -r code

#Get the credentials from AWS and store the response in a variable
creds="$( aws sts get-session-token --serial-number "${MFA}" --token-code "${code}" )"

#Parse the response into separate variables
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$( echo "${creds}" | jq -r .Credentials.AccessKeyId )"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$( echo "${creds}" | jq -r .Credentials.SecretAccessKey )"
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$( echo "${creds}" | jq -r .Credentials.SessionToken )"

#Display the keys to the user for reference/confirm proper working
echo "${access_key}"
echo "${secret_key}"
echo "${session_token}"

#Set the appropriate environment variables
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}"
```

**EDIT:** Two things of note:

1. The parameter substitution is not an issue at all. It works just fine as is, though the other methods suggested in the comments and answer work too. (I used the `jq -r` tip and it works like a charm! Thank you!)
2. I removed the `source` command in my script (on line 3) and then was able to, without any errors of any kind, able to invoke my script as `source aws_mfa_access default`. The `export`ed variables persisted and I am able to use the CLI with no problems.

So why does this not like me using `source` in my script? I've also edited the script to reflect some of the changes.

Comment: Use `jq -r` so that the output of `jq` doesn't have quotes in the first place.

Comment: `source` is equivalent to copy&pasting the script into your shell. It doesn't matter what kind of shebang you put on it.

Comment: `source` runs the script in the current shell. If the current shell is zsh, that means it's going to run in zsh, and must use zsh-compatible syntax. If you want it to run in bash, you need to run it in a different shell. *There is no way around this fact*.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - I had a hunch this was the case, but thought something like `source` would be pretty universal. Let me try @chepner's suggestion given in his/her answer and try again. If you can see what can be fixed in the script, please do let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirect parameter expansion is different in `zsh` than it is in `bash`

```
MFA="arn:aws:iam::${(P)AWS_ACCT_NBR}:mfa/codingincircles"
```

However, you can avoid indirect parameter expansion in the first place by using an associative array to store the account numbers.

```
typeset -A account_numbers
account_numbers[default]=...
account_numbers[sandbox]=...
account_numbers[production]=...
```

Then

```
MFA="arn:aws:iam::${account_numbers[$1]}:mfa/codingincircles"
```

Finally, `source` is not an external command that means "execute a `bash` script here". It's a shell built-in that executes a file *in the current shell*. If the current shell is `bash`, it will attempt to execute the contents of a file as a `bash` script; if it's `zsh`, as a `zsh` script; if it's `dash`, as a `dash` script.

Comment: This is not the real issue. I've edited my question with more clarity on what's going on. Please take a look :)

Comment: Woah! Making this change worked! I wouldn't have expected that this would be the case! What's not clear is how it works. The substitution works just fine, as, if the account number was wrong, i.e., not substituted properly, it would've thrown an error right away. Can you please try and explain this? But thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: `zsh` is simply different from `bash`. `bash` uses `${!name}` for indirect parameter expansion, `zsh` does not. Indirect parameter expansion is not defined in the POSIX standard, so you should not expect every shell that implements it to do so in the same way.

Comment: But like any other failed expansion, it simply expands to the empty string, if that's what you mean by "as if the account number was wrong".

Comment: No, I meant that if the substitution was wrong, it would've thrown an error right away. It didn't, which means that the substitution was correct. However, I could only execute the script as `./aws_mfa_access default`, which would execute in a subshell and not `export` the variables. With the corrected approach to substitution, I'm able to `source` it.